Read message from sevice bus - send to a web api
What I want to do is to read a json message from at Service Bus queue, and then call a REST API with that json message. Exact same format, no need for mapping.
What I have done so far is created a Azure Logic App with a Service Bus trigger.
I call the API with the body of the message.
I get a HTTP 400 Bad Request response with a list of fields that are missing.
The request from the Logic app sends the json doc base64 encoded in the ContentData field,  "ContentTransferEncoding": "Base64"
The Content type in the header is application/json.
If I decode the string and post that json using Postman, it works fine.
Any Ideas?

To resolve this issue, make use of the base64ToString function to decode base64-encoded ContentData.
E.g. instead of
@items('For_each')?['ContentData']

send
@base64ToString(items('For_each')?['ContentData'])

in the body of your HTTP request.
Adapt this solution based on your Logic App code.

I used base64ToString(body('Parse_JSON')?['ContentData']) but your post put me and the right track. Thanks.
